# why c++ singleton need memory_order_acquire

Tags: c++, memory-barriers

```
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
     Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
     std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);        //<--1
     if (tmp == nullptr) {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
         tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         if (tmp == nullptr) {
             tmp = new Singleton;
             assert(tmp != nullptr);    
             std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); //<--2
             m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
         }
     }
     return tmp;
 }
```

here is a common c++ singleton implementation, there are a `release fence` in `2`(marked as above), it is easy to understand, it prevents from reordering `new Singleton`, without this fence, another thread might get an instance without executing construction yet;

what confuses me is that the `acquire fence` in `1`,  `release fence` promises that Singleton construction has been executed then store to m_instance, here, when we fetch instance, we won't get an instance without executing construction, why do we still need a `acquire fence` in `1`?

And, can we replace `atomic_thread_fence` with m_instance operation memroy order, are they same? (show as below)

```
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
     Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
     if (tmp == nullptr) {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
         tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         if (tmp == nullptr) {
             tmp = new Singleton;
             assert(tmp != nullptr);    
             m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_release);
         }
     }
     return tmp;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I believe the shorter version has no bugs or memory races. The release/acquire memory instructions are to insure that singleton's instance will be synchronized correctly and not just the pointer that references it.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd fence superfluous too? Releasing the mutex has release semantics anyways, so when `lock` gets destroyed, everything should be visible anyways, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Erklkoenig no as mutex release occurs after pointer assignment which might result (extremely rarely) in a bug.

Comment: Ah, because other threads might observe the assignment immediately (before the mutex is released) but not the constructor call, so they would see an uninitialized object? An explicit fence right before/after an atomic access with "relaxed" memory order does seem silly indeed.

Comment: Whats the deal with the mutexes and atomics anyway? Why not simply `Singleton* tmp = new Singleton`?

Comment: @eerorika To ensure no two constructor calls happen simultaneously, and that the other threads have to (blocking) wait for the object to become available.

Comment: @Erlkoenig c++ guarantees that static variables are initialised once. There is no need for this complexity as far as I can tell. The compuler is required to take care of synchronisation (since c++11).

Comment: Yes, if static variables are used, which isn't always desired. Also, it is interesting so see how it could work, by implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the second version with acquire/release order for the operations on `m_instance` is correct and equivalent to the first version. In fact, it is even preferable to the first version, because fences affect all preceding (acquire)/succeeding (release) atomic operations, but you only need synchronization of operations on `m_instance`. That's why on some architectures explicit fences are slower.

---

Why do you need acquire/release in the first place? Because you need a happens-before relation between creation of the singleton and usage of the singleton to avoid data races. Suppose the following:

- Thread 1 calls `Singleton::getInstance()` and initializes it; this involves creating a new object and storing the pointer in `m_instance`
- Thread 2 calls `Singleton::getInstance()` and observes the pointer written by Thread 1

Thread 2 will most like *dereference* the pointer to access the object it points to, and this access is most likely non-atomic. So you have two non-atomic accesses to the object - one during creation and one when using the object. If these are not ordered by a happens-before relation, then this is a data race.

So how do we establish a happens-before relation? By storing the pointer with `memory_order_release`, and reading it with `memory_order_acquire`. When an acquire-load operation observes the value written by a release-store, the load *synchronizes-with* the store, thereby establishing a happens-before relation. Further, construction of the object is *sequenced-before* the store, and the load is sequenced-before dereferenciation (sequenced-before also implies happens-before), and since happens-before is *transitive*, it follows that construction happens-before dereferenciation.

For more details on the C++ memory model I recommend this paper which I have co-authored: [Memory Models for C/C++ Programmers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04432)

Comment: what I know is  `memory_order_acquire` prevents reading operations behind the fence from reordering front the fence to build a relation `happen-before`, but here I can't see there are any reading operations need to be prevented from reordering by `memory_order_acquire`. we use `memory_order_release` to store the` m_instance` which should promise that object has finished creation and construction then atomic store it, it seems that `one during creation and when one using the object` will not gona be happen, why do we need a acquire fence?

Comment: Is there are an possibility, there are an `invalidate queue` in each core for accelerating synchronize cache in x86,  `data update message` will be pushed to this queue when we use `memory_order_release` to store data in order to inform others cores, others cores need to execute some instrucions to get this `data update message` from queue to update data,  here `memory_order_acquire` plays the role in getting `data update message` and `update message`, is it just an acceleration optimization？Without this, following `lock_gurad` has the same semantics but costs more

Comment: You should avoid arguing based on possible reorderings. The standard does not say anything about reorderings, it only defines the (inter-thread) happens-before relation. If or when instructions can be reordered is merely a result of applying the rules for the happens-before relation. In your case, you need a happens-before relation between the objects construction and its usage to ensure that the thread using the object "sees" the fully constructed object; this is not about reordering, but visibility. This happens-before relation is established via the acquire/release operations.